# NetSuite: HTML Template table cut off because too much data

Tags: html, html-table, netsuite

Our item fulfilments sometimes have hundreds of serial numbers in the inventory detail. when the fulfilment is printed the serial numbers are listed. They only appear on the first page though and then they are cut off. How do I get the table cell to continue on the next page and the next so all serial numbers are listed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your serials number a separate tr on the table.  See this SuiteAnswer for more details: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/66550/